# How do I see Plone control panel

Tags: plone

I've been asked to make some changes to a Plone site that has been set up by someone else, I've not used it before so I'm struggling a bit.

I've logged in (using the link at the bottom of the site) and I can then see all the options to edit the page I am looking at. But I cannot seem to get to the central dashboard/control panel. I can't see any link when I'm logged in, and I've searched the docs/Google and can't see a URL for the dashboard.

Could someone please let me know how to reach the main dashboard. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link should be in the user's menu (that also has "log out" etc.), where it is called "Site setup", or you can go directly to `https://your_site/plone_control_panel`.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical and stable URL is `https://your_site/@@overview-controlpanel`.

The `plone_control_panel` was removed: https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/1255